# kotlin- change decimal places on multiple fragments from one fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

for my app i read in multiple values from Bluetooth connected sensors. One fragment allows you to edit the sensors and another fragment shows all values in a tableView.
On a third settings fragment, i want to be able to change the decimal places the values on all fragments appear.

i know to change the decimal format i use the following code.

```
 var form = DecimalFormat("#,###.##") // number format
```

and to add this format to the values do the following

```
form.format(temperature)
```

currently i have a radio group, with each radio button set to change the how many decimal places in the variable form.

how do i make this change appear across all fragments not just the setting fragments? will i need a shared view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shared `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#viewmodel) is good fit for this problem, simply create a `ViewModel` with `form` property and in every fragment get an instance of `ViewModel` associated with activity as

```
private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Now you can update the `form` property on radio change as

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
    val format = when(checkedId){
        R.id.radio_two ->   TWO_DECIMAL_PLACES
        R.id.radio_three -> THREE_DECIMAL_PLACES
        else -> DEFAULT_FORMAT
     }
     viewModel.form = DecimalFormat(format)
}
```

After this simply use value of this property before showing data

Comment: +1 but you might want to make ``form`` a ``LiveData`` or similar (with the usual setters etc) so your other fragments can ``observe`` it, and automatically update to reflect the new setting. But if the data updates often enough you could just check the current value of ``form`` when you display it instead, yeah - whatever fits best!